Were any of the aliens in Battlestar Galactica played by animals in suits?
Related to my other question Were other robots in Battlestar Galactica animals in suits? which I asked after finding out that the robot Moffit the daggit was played by Evie, a 3 year old chimpanzee in a suit, was this technique used for any of the aliens in the series?

I can't help thinking that the "original" (1978) series episode "The Lost Warrior" had one or two animals lightly dressed up to make them look alien - not "suits" but bits of fur and rubber prosthetics.
